# how could I convert a table containing the output below in a Python dictionary?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

[image]

```
Filesystem           Type       1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda             ext4          245671     47009    181459  21% /initlo
/dev/loop7           squashfs       39552     39552         0 100% /
none                 tmpfs          65536      1064     64472   2% /tmp
none                 aufs           65536      1064     64472   2% /dev
none                 tmpfs         510184        24    510160   0% /dev/shm
none                 aufs           65536      1064     64472   2% /etc
none                 aufs           65536      1064     64472   2% /var
none                 aufs           65536      1064     64472   2% /www
none                 aufs           65536      1064     64472   2% /mcl
none                 aufs           65536      1064     64472   2% /eds
```

Want to create a dictionary(key as header of table and values should be as per their respective column). Please help to create this dictionary. Please click on link to get the pic of the table.

Comment: Hi, you will get a better response, if you put in some effort to formulate your question in a proper way (write at least a sentence, etc.). Also if you tell us more about the context, to reassure us that you are not trying to use us to do school homework. Finally, I suggest you formulate it as a **question**, not as a demand for a solution.

Comment: Want to compare 'ext4' filesystem which is under 'Type' column by using python.
This table form comes from linux command and i need to check whether 'ext4' file system comes under 'Type' column whenver i run the command.

Comment: OK, so let us know how far you have come in your search for a solution. Do you know how to execute a shell command and store the results in a string?

Comment: i have a function written for the same to store the output command.

Answer (score 1):

The output seems to be a tab separated string/list of tab separated strings. I would change the complete string to a list of strings

```
def make_dict(input_list):
    final_output = []
    headers = input_list[0].strip().split("\t")
    for line in input_list[1:]:
        line = line.strip().split("\t")
        final_output.append({key: value for key,value in zip(headers, line)} )
    return final_output
Input_str = """Filesystem           Type       1K-blocks      Used Available Use% 
Mounted on
/dev/sda             ext4          245671     47009    181459  21% /initlo
/dev/loop7           squashfs       39552     39552         0 100% /
none                 tmpfs          65536      1064     64472   2% /tmp
none                 aufs           65536      1064     64472   2% /dev
none                 tmpfs         510184        24    510160   0% /dev/shm
none                 aufs           65536      1064     64472   2% /etc
none                 aufs           65536      1064     64472   2% /var
none                 aufs           65536      1064     64472   2% /www
none                 aufs           65536      1064     64472   2% /mcl
none                 aufs           65536      1064     64472   2% /eds
"""
input_list = Input_str.split("\n")
print(make_dict(input_list))
```

Output:

```
   [{'Filesystem': '/dev/sda', 'Type': '', '1K-blocks': 'ext4', 'Used': ' 245671', 'Available': '47009', 'Use%': '181459', 'Mounted on': '21%'}, {'Filesystem': '/dev/loop7', 'Type': 'squashfs', '1K-blocks': '39552', 'Used': '39552', 'Available': '0', 'Use%': '100%', 'Mounted on': '/'}, {'Filesystem': 'none', 'Type': 'tmpfs', '1K-blocks': ' 65536', 'Used': '1064', 'Available': '64472', 'Use%': '2%', 'Mounted on': '/tmp'}, {'Filesystem': 'none', 'Type': 'aufs', '1K-blocks': '65536', 'Used': '1064', 'Available': '64472', 'Use%': '2%', 'Mounted on': '/dev'}, {'Filesystem': 'none', 'Type': 'tmpfs', '1K-blocks': '510184', 'Used': '', 'Available': '24', 'Use%': '510160', 'Mounted on': '0%t/dev/shm'}, {'Filesystem': 'none', 'Type': 'aufs', '1K-blocks': '65536', 'Used': '1064', 'Available': '64472', 'Use%': '2%', 'Mounted on': '/etc'}, {'Filesystem': 'none', 'Type': 'aufs', '1K-blocks': '65536', 'Used': '1064', 'Available': '64472', 'Use%': '2%', 'Mounted on': '/var'}, {'Filesystem': 'none', 'Type': 'aufs', '1K-blocks': '65536', 'Used': '1064', 'Available': '64472', 'Use%': '2%', 'Mounted on': '/www'}, {'Filesystem': 'none', 'Type': 'aufs', '1K-blocks': '65536', 'Used': '1064', 'Available': '64472', 'Use%': '2%', 'Mounted on': '/mcl'}, {'Filesystem': 'none', 'Type': 'aufs', '1K-blocks': '65536', 'Used': '1064', 'Available': '64472', 'Use%': '2%', 'Mounted on': '/eds'}]
```

Comment: I like your solution: simple, effective. My only suggestion would to put the `split` action right into the function (and I would use `splitlines()`).

Comment: Yeah could do that, but most likely the user will get the output of this system command as a list already.

Comment: I suggest an amendment to make your solution work in all cases (it failed in my test, because the separators were whitespaces instead of tabs; it can easily happen for a number of reasons). Instead of using the `split('\t')`method, you could use: `re.split('\s+', s.strip())`. I created a `split_spaces` function for that.

Comment: showing error as headers=re.split('\s+', s.strip())
NameError: global name 's' is not defined

Comment: Of course: you would have to use the proper name for `s` (`line` and `headers`) . I could propose a full solution if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the inspiration from @Rishikesh Jha (thanks), here is my proposed answer (*without using high-level libraries like pandas*):

```
import re

INPUT = """Filesystem           Type       1K-blocks      Used Available Use%
Mounted on
/dev/sda             ext4          245671     47009    181459  21% /initlo
/dev/loop7           squashfs       39552     39552         0 100% /
none                 tmpfs          65536      1064     64472   2% /tmp
none                 aufs           65536      1064     64472   2% /dev
none                 tmpfs         510184        24    510160   0% /dev/shm
none                 aufs           65536      1064     64472   2% /etc
none                 aufs           65536      1064     64472   2% /var
none                 aufs           65536      1064     64472   2% /www
none                 aufs           65536      1064     64472   2% /mcl
none                 aufs           65536      1064     64472   2% /eds
"""

def split_spaces(s):
    "Split a string into a list, using spaces/tabs as separators"
    return re.split('\s+', s.strip())

def make_dict(input):
    "Convert a string containing a table into a list of dictionaries"
    input_list = input.splitlines()
    output_list = []
    # get the keys:
    keys = split_spaces(input_list[0])
    # get the list of dictionaries:
    for line in input_list[1:]:
        values = split_spaces(line)
        output_list.append({key: value for key,value in zip(keys, values)} )
    return output_list



print("Table: ", make_dict(INPUT))
row1 = d[0]
print("First row:", row1)
print("The type of first row is:", row1['Type'])
```

And here is the result:

```
Table:  [{'Filesystem': 'Mounted', 'Type': 'on'}, {'Filesystem': '/dev/sda', 'Type': 'ext4', '1K-blocks': '245671', 'Used': '47009', 'Available': '181459', 'Use%': '21%'}, {'Filesystem': '/dev/loop7', 'Type': 'squashfs', '1K-blocks': '39552', 'Used': '39552', 'Available': '0', 'Use%': '100%'}, {'Filesystem': 'none', 'Type': 'tmpfs', '1K-blocks': '65536', 'Used': '1064', 'Available': '64472', 'Use%': '2%'}, {'Filesystem': 'none', 'Type': 'aufs', '1K-blocks': '65536', 'Used': '1064', 'Available': '64472', 'Use%': '2%'}, {'Filesystem': 'none', 'Type': 'tmpfs', '1K-blocks': '510184', 'Used': '24', 'Available': '510160', 'Use%': '0%'}, {'Filesystem': 'none', 'Type': 'aufs', '1K-blocks': '65536', 'Used': '1064', 'Available': '64472', 'Use%': '2%'}, {'Filesystem': 'none', 'Type': 'aufs', '1K-blocks': '65536', 'Used': '1064', 'Available': '64472', 'Use%': '2%'}, {'Filesystem': 'none', 'Type': 'aufs', '1K-blocks': '65536', 'Used': '1064', 'Available': '64472', 'Use%': '2%'}, {'Filesystem': 'none', 'Type': 'aufs', '1K-blocks': '65536', 'Used': '1064', 'Available': '64472', 'Use%': '2%'}, {'Filesystem': 'none', 'Type': 'aufs', '1K-blocks': '65536', 'Used': '1064', 'Available': '64472', 'Use%': '2%'}]
First row: {'Filesystem': '/dev/sda', 'Type': 'ext4', '1K-blocks': 245671, 'Used': 47009, 'Available': 181459, 'Use%': '21%', 'Mounted': '/initlo', 'on': nan}
The type of first row is: ext4
```

#### Note

The `split_spaces` functions be robust enough to work anyway if you have several whitespaces or tabs or even a mix of both. See the [definition of `\s`in a regular expression](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_whitespace.asp); the symbol `+`means "one or more".

Comment: return re.split('\s+', s.strip())
in this for 's', it is throwing error as global name's' not defined.

Comment: Funny, it worked for me. s should not be a global variable, but is the argument of `split_spaces` function. Did you put the `import re` statement at the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding the question is "how could I convert a string containing the output above in a Python dictionary"?

One possible solution is to let [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) do the footwork for you (supposing you have your table in a file):

```
import pandas
input_file = "input.txt"
t = pandas.read_csv(input_file, sep='\s+')

print("Here is the dictionary of dictionaries:")
d = t.to_dict(orient='index')
print("List of keys:", d.keys())
row1 = d[0]
print("First row:", row1)
print("The type of first row is:", row1['Type'])
```

The trick is in the separator argument (`\s+`: one or more spaces/tabs)

This is the output:

```
Here is the dictionary of dictionaries:
List of keys: dict_keys([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
First row: {'Filesystem': '/dev/sda', 'Type': 'ext4', '1K-blocks': 245671, 'Used': 47009, 'Available': 181459, 'Use%': '21%', 'Mounted': '/initlo', 'on': nan}
The type of first row is: ext4
```

Comment: Any solution without using pandas?

Comment: I suggest you use the solution proposed by @RishikeshJha